# onTouch giving strange results in getX android

Tags: android, touch-event

I am trying to move a image when you touch on it. I realize that when I was moving the image makes strange things (it sometimes do it well and others move to different places). I made a Log.d with the getX value and this is what I get:

```
 03-16 19:26:23.569: D/eventX:(15450): 23.0
 03-16 19:26:23.599: D/eventX:(15450): 91.0
 03-16 19:26:23.629: D/eventX:(15450): 20.0
 03-16 19:26:23.659: D/eventX:(15450): 89.0
 03-16 19:26:23.689: D/eventX:(15450): 17.0
 03-16 19:26:23.719: D/eventX:(15450): 87.0
 03-16 19:26:23.749: D/eventX:(15450): 14.0
 03-16 19:26:23.779: D/eventX:(15450): 85.0
 03-16 19:26:23.809: D/eventX:(15450): 11.0
 03-16 19:26:23.839: D/eventX:(15450): 83.0
 03-16 19:26:23.879: D/eventX:(15450): 8.0
```

As you can see one is the good value (the value of the position that I touch it) and other that has no sense. Someone knows the reason why?

Here is the peace of code that I am using...

```
  head.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent ev) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (ev.getAction()) {


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(head.getLayoutParams().width, head.getLayoutParams().height);
                Log.d("eventX:", ((Float)ev.getX()).toString());
                layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) ev.getX();
                head.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                count = false;

                break;
            }
```

Comment: show the code that you are printing with, etc

Comment: There you have... if you need more code just tell me

Comment: does the problem persist if you use getRawX and do no cast to a Float and call tostring? you do not need to cast or call tostring.

Comment: getRawX was what I needed! It is making me good values! Thanks a lot!

Comment: ill make this an answer now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the typical `getX()` function is completely tied to specific view that dispatched the `MotionEvent` and returns a coordinate relative to that view. In your case it seems likely that multiple views are dispatching the event and you are getting multiple unexpected values.

In any case, using [`getRawX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX%28%29) will allow you to get a consistent and absolute coordinate, and will resolve the confusion of all the different coordinates.